Call useEffect and useLayoutEffect from another component
I have a component that, upon button click, will hide a set of buttons and perform an animation before the data is displayed.
const myComponent = () => {
  const [hideBtns, setHideBtns] = useState(true);
  const [openPageDescription, setOpenPageDescription] = useState(true);
  const [transitionEffect, setTransitionEffect] = useState(true);
  const [showPageDescription, setShowPageDescription] = useState(false);
  const transEffect = useRef(null);
  const btns = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (openPageDescription) {
      setHideBtns(false);
      setTransitionEffect(true);
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setShowPageDescription(true);
      }, 530);
      return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [openPageDescription]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
      gsap.set(".transition-effect", { background: "black" });
      gsap.to(".transition-effect", {
        duration: 0.6,
        scale: 3.5,
        //code
      });
    }, hideBtns);
    return () => ctx.revert();
  }, [hideBtns]);

  return (
    <right className="container" ref={transEffect}>
      <div className="btn-set-container">
        {showPageDescription && <PageDescription close={close} />}
        <div className="btn-set" ref={btns}>
          <button
            className="btn-right"
            data-id="yo"
            onClick={() => setOpenPageDescription(true)}
          >
            Page Description
          </button>
        </div>
        {transitionEffect && <div className="transition-effect"></div>}
      </div>
    </right>
  );
};

It works great.
However, I am now wanting to perform that animation (where it always performs) from a button clicked in a different component. My first thought is to put the two effects in a shared, parent component, but it seems to me I would then have to pass down the effects. Passing down a useEffect and useLayoutEffect? I have never come across that before. Could someone give me insight on the correct way of thinking/approaching this problem?

You do not need to pass down an effect. All you need to do is lift your state up.
You lift your state up to have a state variable in the lowest common ancestor of the two react components. Now Trigger component updates the state using a button click. And Animated component receives the update state value (as a prop). And here the two effects run with that prop as a dependency.

I just got back from implementing what you said... Wow! What power!
